# Longtable monospace font

Tags: fonts, longtable, typewriter

How do I format all the text in a longtable to monospace. Adding `\texttt{` before or after the `\begin{longtable}` and a `}` at the end gives me a

```
Runaway argument?
{ \begin {longtable}{lll} 
! Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete.
```

error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest method:

```
\begingroup
\ttfamily
\begin{longtable}...
...
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
```

Comment: That works fine, but the font size is reset. How can I change the font size in a group environment?

Comment: `\begin{ttfamily}` ... `\end{ttfamily}` also works. Although I don't like it personally.